# How to only allow contract owner to mint token?

Tags: solidity, erc-721, mint

I think I saw it somewhere before but can't find it again. I need to allow only the contract owner to mint ERC721 token in the contract. Correct me, I think it has to do with using `require`. I could try to code it but I'd like to follow best practices thus I'm looking for opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `Ownable` https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/access-control#ownership-and-ownable and use `onlyOwner` modifier on your function;

```
function mint() onlyOwner {
}
```

or you can use:

```
require(msg.sender == owner, "Must be owner");
```

variable `address owner` should be initialized beforehand.

`msg.sender` is the sender of the transaction

Ownable has a lot of features, like `transferOwnership`, `renounceOwnership`, getter and events

Comment: Awesome. Super clear. Thank you.